# installing stack builder for Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, installation, odoo, taskstackbuilder

when I try to install stack builder after installing postgres, this error message appears :
Failed to parse the application  list: http://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.xml
please help me solve this problem

I am trying to install stuck builder after installing postgresql